# Issue with Raspberry pi 3.0 i2c SMBus

Tags: python, i2c, raspberry-pi3

I am new to the raspberry pi and I have been working through some i2c examples. I am receiving an ***IO Error: [Errno 22]Invalid argument*** when I run the code below:

```
import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
addr = 0xa0
data = 0x20
bus.write_byte(addr, data)
```

Would someone please explain why this might be happening? I can see the device using the i2cdetect in the terminal but my code is failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen when you use an invalid address in the function.
You can check addr is correct or not. Please have a look on slave address.